# Hiding and showing div id using a vector map

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress

I have created a vector map of the united states, and given each state a link of "#insertstatename" for example "#florida" and "#utah". When each state is clicked, a list should appear with the state name. To simplify the code, I have just shortened what appears to the state name. I can't get the states to hide before the link is clicked.

Only one state and list should be shown at a time, so when one is clicked it hides another.

Here is my html

```
<div id="florida">
<p> florida </p>
</div>

<div id="utah">
<p> utah </p>
</div>
```

and here is my script

```
<script>
 jQuery('.resume') .hide()
jQuery('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function(event) {
jQuery('.resume') .hide()
    var target = jQuery(this).attr('href');

    jQuery('.resume'+target).toggle();
    e.preventDefault();
});
</script>
```

Comment: I added class="resume" to the divs which i know was necessary but it still will not work, now they are just hidden.

Comment: I can't make sense of your comment. Care to elaborate ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It is good that you have simplified your code in your question, but it would help if you created a working code snippet it includes all the basic information needed to make it work (e.g. the missing `resume` classes and a sample of your `<a>` link that triggers your jQuery). Without seeing all the relevant code we can't tell whats going wrong, but with a short working example I'm sure we can help :)  See [How to create a runnable code snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: In the html, it is now <div class="resume" id="state name">

Comment: @deg i have included a better example above

Comment: @FluffyKitten I am using a wordpress plugin called RVM - Responsive Vector Maps that allows you to add links to individual states or regions. It is fairly limited, but I am able to add http links or id links like I have ( #utah and #florida)

Comment: @FluffyKitten you can see a live example at http://elementsnew.wpengine.com/?page_id=95

Comment: Please include a simplified working example as a code snippet in your question, so that we have only the code that's relevant to the question and can work on it directly. There is too much code on a full site. Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/w1nyzdze/

```js
$('div.resume').hide();
$('a').click(function(){
 $($(this).data('href')).slideDown().siblings('div.resume').hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a data-href="#florida">florida</a>
<a data-href="#utah">utah</a>
<br/>

<div class="resume" id="florida">
<p> florida </p>
</div>

<div class="resume" id="utah">
<p> utah </p>
</div>
```

Instead of using `href` in `anchor`, I've used `data-href` **data attribute**.

`Onclick` of `anchor` tag below  respective `div` will be show and for hiding please use `jQuery` `siblings`.

Hope this will help you.